# Hyperlink in latex

Tags: pdf, latex, pdflatex

How can I shorten a URL in hypertext in latex
for example
that's my URL https://www.linkedin.com/in/hassan-bosha-8178611b9/
and I want to shorten it into Hassan Bosha
I'm using
\linkedin{Hassan Bosha}
to make a hypertext with the LinkedIn logo
How can I shorten it?

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre] so we can see which class and packages you use.